# Unable to resolve a haste module after upgrading to React Native 0.56

Tags: react-native, babeljs

Until React Native 0.55 –included– I could call `import {something} from 'hasteModuleSomething'`, where `hasteModuleSomething.js` existed and had the following lines on the top:

```
/**
* @providesModule hasteModuleSomething
* @flow
*/
```

It also breaks the test suite, that uses jest.

**What is the expected behavior?**
I should be able to keep using the current haste modules architecture, at least while the company moves slowly towards a more conventional imports strategy.

**This is the only Metro Bundler configuration file I have**

```
// rn-cli.config.js
const blacklist = require('metro/src/blacklist')

module.exports = {
  getBlacklistRE () {
    return blacklist([/react-native\/local-cli\/core\/__fixtures__.*/])
  },
}
```

Building from a MacOSX, Node.js v8.13, yarn v1.7.0, React v16.4

If this is not a bug (probably is a design decision) could you give me some directions on how to recover the functionality? I opened the original issue here https://github.com/facebook/metro/issues/200

Comment: Did you manage to get it work?

Comment: No. I eventually had to find and replace everything, little by little with some team help.